# Can JAX-WS map an XSD date (xs:dateTime) to a Java Calendar?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jax-ws

Can [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) map an [XML schema date](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) (`xs:dateTime`), including its time zone, to a Java [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.

**Contract first approach**
You need to use the `jaxb:javaType` element. There's some general information [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) and an example of what you need to do [here](http://www.codenes.com/blog/?p=129).

**Contract last approach**

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getTest")
public Calendar getTest(@WebParam(name = "input") Calendar input) {
  input.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
  return input
}
```

Will map to:

```
<xs:complexType name="getTest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="input" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="getTestResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="return" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: What can I do if I use the Contract Last approach as described in http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/why-contract-first.html (generate the WSDL and schema from Java source) rather than the Contract First approach which your example assumes?

Comment: @Derek - I've updated my answer but I haven't tried the contract last approach before.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but without `@WebParam` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it would work by default; JAXB (data binder that JAX-WS implementations use) should know how to convert between XML values and java.util.Calendar.

If not, the default date/time datatype used with XML is javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar, which can be converted using method toGregorianCalendar() (which will be of type java.util.GregorianCalendar, a java.util.Calendar subclass). So one possibility is to get data bound to XMLGregorianCalendar, then just convert back/forth when accessing. This can also be automated by using XMLJavaTypeAdapter.